# Low Volume When Using AudioToolbox in iOS

Tags: ios, volume, audiotoolbox

I have used AV Foundation before but my latest project require AudioToolbox, I changed my code and now the audio playback is extremely low, specially over the headphone jack, regardless of the device volume.

What I really want is 100% volume always, even if the device is set to 50% or whatever.

Thanks !

Comment: From a user perspective, that sounds horrible. With my headphones it would be deafening. Why would you do this??

Comment: Im sending tones to a DTMF decoder for communication. The user will never hear it.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Has anyone managed to solve this?

Comment: @user2067377 have you managed to find a solution?
I encounter the problem but only over the headphones.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add these codes?

```
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker, error: nil)
    session.setActive(true, error: nil)
```